# InkCanvas MVVM binding in UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, inkcanvas

I have a list with InkStrokeContainer in a ListView and I try to bind the InkCanvas to it. In WPF the InkCanvas had a Strokes attribut but in UWP its not available. Another idea was to bind to an InkPresenter but how?

Then my idea was to create a InkCanvasControl which extends from InkCanvas and create the Property for the Strokes.

```
public InkStrokeContainer Strokes
{
    get
    {
        return this.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer;
    }
    set
    {
        this.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer = value;
    }
}
```

But with this I got the error: "Cannot assign property Strokes"... 
I used it this way:

```
<controls:InkCanvasControl Strokes="{Binding Strokes}"></controls:InkCanvasControl>
```

And the binding is from my ViewModel.

Comment: Hi there, any update? Did my answer solve your problem? Is it an acceptable answer?

Comment: god damn.. i did not get a message for youre answer... I will try it in the next days. Sorry for that.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that the `Strokes` property you've created is not a dependency property, so it won't support binding and that's why you got the error. To solve this problem, you can register `Strokes` property as a dependency property like following:

```
public InkStrokeContainer Strokes
{
    get { return (InkStrokeContainer)GetValue(StrokesProperty); }
    set { SetValue(StrokesProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Strokes",
    typeof(InkStrokeContainer), typeof(InkCanvasControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnLabelChanged)));

private static void OnLabelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (d as InkCanvasControl).InkPresenter.StrokeContainer = (InkStrokeContainer)e.NewValue;
}
```

For more info, please see [Custom dependency properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties).